# How do I Create a portal so students can upload and download work from a network drive via sharepoint?

Tags: file-upload, download, network-drive

How do I Create a portal so students can upload and download work from a network drive via SharePoint 2016?

I'm quite new to SharePoint and this isn't really the best way to use but it a short-term fix to a long-term project.

Thanks

Comment: Please could you provide more details and perhaps add a scenario to get more relevant answers?  Are you trying to make network drive available on SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its simple , create an library app somewhere in your site and start uploading documents there.